# Linq to entities get first or last from 2million rows

Tags: c#-4.0, lambda, linq-to-entities

I'm learning LINQ to Entities in C# .NET4.0 Winforms.

I have a MSSQL database table with over 2million rows, eventually more and I need to just pull back the first record or the last record in the database.

I tried getting the last record but it doesn't seem to want to work for me :( It builds okay, but during RunTime I get a

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'StockTraderRobotDT.IntradayFuturesTick       
Last[IntradayFuturesTick](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[StockTraderRobotDT.IntradayFuturesTick])' 
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I'm doing this...

```
using (DataFeedEntities db = new DataFeedEntities())
{
   IntradayFuturesTick tick = db.IntradayFuturesTicks.Last();
}
```

I know it's probably an easy answer but I'm still getting my head around LINQ.

Thanks for your help.

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sort the results in descending order then use the Take extension method.

```
using (DataFeedEntities db = new DataFeedEntities())
{
    IntradayFuturesTick tick = db.IntradayFuturesTicks
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
       .Take(1)
       .Single();
}
```

You could also use First instead of Take, but I'm not sure if that will return only a single result in the database query.

Comment: Charles, this was perfect, it worked like a charm, I was worried about it taking a long time if I had to load the 2 million rows to re-order etc... however I realized that it doesn't actually load it, it just sends MS SQL the specific TSQL required :D  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.IntradayFuturesTicks.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23105706)